# PHP Issue Adding 0.001 to 0.001?

Tags: php, decimal, addition

Hi I cannot seem to be able to work out how to incrementally add a very small number?

```
$val    = 0.000000001;
$add    = 0.000000001;
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $val = bcadd($val, $add, 9);
    echo $val.'<br>';
}

// echo
// 0.000000000
// 0.000000000
// . . .
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: It's about the represenation and precision of numbers. I'll give you link to the explanation of floating numbers you should read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29637/Five-Tips-for-Floating-Point-Programming

Comment: bcadd() expects string representations of numeric values, not floats

Comment: change $val and $add to strings, e.g. put them in quotes. then it will work.

Comment: why not just do `echo number_format($val+$add,9);` is there some primary reason you want to use bcadd rather than just doing a simple addition?

Comment: casting a float to string is different from just writing it as a string to start with, hence "put them in quotes". When you do `(string)`PHP typejuggles the floats and loss of precision is to be expected.

Comment: Interesting about the timings I'd have assumed the pure add was faster than bc add so I did some tests add1 22.102177143097 bcadd1 22.353304862976, add2 22.25861120224 bcadd2 22.675615787506, add3 22.230845928192 bcadd3 22.399045944214.  They're so very similar but on every run its coming out pure add is quicker which is interesting as its different to your results.  Are you using an AMD processor by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$val    = "0.000000001";
$add    = "0.000000001";
for ($i=0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $val = bcadd($val, $add, 9);
    echo $val.'<br>';
}
exit;

?>
```

it works :) as some collegues explained bacadd needs arguments to be string.